# How can I determine where in the PDF to place content using Zend PDF?

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating a PDF using Zend's built-in PDF engine; however how can I determine in what dimension (height, width - x, y) where to place the text on a plain A4 layout page?

I understand 0,0 is bottom,right (for some reason) - but what is the top/left values?

Answer (score 0):

Call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on your PDF Page object to get the page size and figure it out from there.

The value is in "points" (1/72 of an inch).

[More Info in Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html)